# What would be equivalent of Number(4) of Oracle database to MySQL Datatype?

Tags: mysql, oracle, types, numbers

What would be equivalent of Number(4) of Oracle database to MySQL Datatype ?

Comment: What is `Number(4)` and what does it return in Oracle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Oracle:

> The NUMBER datatype stores fixed and
>   floating-point numbers. Numbers of
>   virtually any magnitude can be stored
>   and are guaranteed portable among
>   different systems operating Oracle, up
>   to 38 digits of precision.

7,456,123.89 as NUMBER(9) is stored as 7456124.

[Oracle Native DataTypes](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/datatype.htm)

In MySQL:

You could use any of the following datatypes since you don't want to store the decimal part of the value...

```
SMALLINT( )  -32768 to 32767 normal 0 to 65535 UNSIGNED.
MEDIUMINT( ) -8388608 to 8388607 normal 0 to 16777215 UNSIGNED.
INT( )   -2147483648 to 2147483647 normal 0 to 4294967295 UNSIGNED.
BIGINT( )    -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807 normal 0 to 18446744073709551615 UNSIGNED.
```

[MySql DataTypes](http://www.htmlite.com/mysql003.php)